# Jump to agendaweek from month view when date is picked

Tags: fullcalendar

> I would like for the user to be able to jump to the agendaWeek view
>   from the month view after selecting a date and that week view should
>   contain selected date in it.Can anyone suggest a way to achieve that
>   functionality?
>
> ```
> if(view.name == 'month'){
>          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/783/

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
},
```

Comment: No tried this. its not taking me to correct date week.

Comment: Works for me, did you try the fiddle?

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke Maybe I misunderstood your question, but if not I think this achieves what you wanted.